# Passing a string as a reference in Java?

Tags: java

I don't think i have the terminology correct, haven't been one for that. What i'm trying to do is get a string back , then use it to run functions. .. Example :

```
int slotNumber = ((j*3)+i+1);
String slotString = "slot"+slotNumber;
```

Regularly I can do this :

```
slot12.Draw();
```

And I want to be able to do this :

```
slotString.Draw();
```

With it substituting slotString with slot12 in a dynamic scenario. If i truly have to i could do something similar to :

```
if (slotString == slot1) slot1.Draw();
if (slotString == slot2) slot2.Draw();
```

And such, but i dont really want to use x number of lines for x number of slots.

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Would a `Map<String, Slot>` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use a HashMap where the key is the slotNumber and the value points to the slot. Then you could do something like the following.

```
//Initialize at the start of your program
HashMap<int, Slot> SlotHash = new HashMap<int, Slot>();

//Code to retrieve slot and call Draw().
Slot select = SlotHash.get(slotNumber);
select.Draw();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use a Map if your slots are sparsely-packed. If they're densely-packed, you might be able to use an array of slots. In either case, you do the slot lookup based on index and then call Draw on the looked-up slot.

Answer (score 0):

You would have something like this:

```
Slot slot1 = new Slot("slot1");
Slot slot2 = new Slot("slot2");
SlotController controller = new SlotController();
controller.add(slot1);controller.add(slot2);

String someSlotNumber = ".....";
controller.draw(someSlotNumber);
```

See the definition of the classes below:

```
class SlotController {
    Map<String, Slot> slotMap = new HashMap<String, Slot>();
    public void addSlot(Slot aSlot) {
        slotMap.put(aSlot.getSlotName(), aSlot);
    }

    public void draw(String slotName) {
        slotMap.get(slotName).draw();
    }


}

class Slot {
    private String slotName;
    public Slot(String name){
        slotName = name;
    }

    public String getSlotName() {
        return slotName;
    }

    public void draw() {

    }
}
```